# Executar script a cada 1000 registros consultados

Tags: php

Estou precisando executar um script a cada 1000 registros consultados no banco de dados. Um exemplo simples para me ajudar é colocar um `<br><br>` a cada 1000 registros.

```
<?php

// Conectando com o banco de dados
require_once("../conecta.php");

// Chama classe para capturar os registros
require_once("excelwriter.class.php");

// Conta a quantidade de registros
$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT nomeUser, emailUser FROM si_login WHERE nomeUser != '' AND emailUser != ''");
$contador = mysql_num_rows($consulta);

// Instrução até chegar na quantidade final de registros
while($contador = mysql_num_rows($consulta)){

    // aqui irá o script a cada 1000 registros.

}

?>
```

Tenho 13640 usuários e estou criando 1 arquivo de captação de e-mails para cada 1000 usuários. Com o código que foi passado, ele gera 13 arquivos e tem um sobra de 640 usuários que ficam pra traz pois não atingiu contador 1000. Assim ficam 13 arquivos em vez de 14, o último guardaria não 1000, mais o restante (640).

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Só para lhe ajudar a se acostumar com nossa filosofia, que é diferente de um fórum, dê uma olhada em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior, especialmente o 3o. item. Se ainda não leu, seria bom dar uma olhada em [about], você ganha uma medalha. Você pode usar o [edit] para deixar sua pergunta com o jeito de uma pergunta direta e limpa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nenhuma das soluções apresentadas atendem o requerimento de executar determinada rotina também para os registros que não atingirem um monte de 1000.

Com PHP não é bom apenas separar lógica da apresentação, PHP do HTML, mas é bom também separar lógicas diferentes em meio a um mesmo código.

No seu caso me refiro ao loop para leitura do recurso retornado pelo MySQL. Esse loop deve servir para ler o recurso do MySQL. E ponto!

Qualquer coisa além disso vai sobrecarregar a aplicação, talvez até impedindo ela de continuar adequadamente.

Se você separar a tarefa em dois laços diferentes, mesmo que você desperdice um pouco de performance (o que para 13 mil registros não é quase nada), você poderá manipular a estrutura gerada pelo primeiro `while`:

```
$records = array();

while( $rows = mysql_num_rows( $query ) ) {

    // Popula $records
}

// Faz alguma coisa com $records, itera essa nova matriz e aplica sua rotina
```

A diferença aqui é que **$records**, agora, tem todos os dados que você precisa de uma só vez e agora basta quebrar esse grande array de 13 mil registros em 14 array menores com [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/array_chunk):

```
$records = array_chunk( $records, 1000, true );
```

Simples assim. Se você depurar **$records** com `var_dump()` (ou `print_r`) antes e depois de ter passado ele por `array_chunk()`, você verá que o que era uma matriz unidimensional (assumindo que você tenha populado ele correta e unidimensionalmente dentro do `while`) agora é uma, no mínimo, bidimensional.

E poderá ver perfeitamente que todos os novos arrays têm 1000 índices, de zero à 999, exceto o último, que terá 640, que é justamente o que você precisa para, num laço sequencial, aplicar sua rotina à todos os 13640 registros.

Comment: -1 por afirmar uma inverdade no começo. ambas as rotinas passam por TODOS os registros individualmente, e ENTRE cada pacote de 1000 faz o exemplo solicitado pelo autor. Bastaria por um "echo" dentro do loop pra confirmar. Além de tudo você está resolvendo com 2 loops o que pode ser feito em um só. Vide comentário: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15869/executar-script-a-cada-1000-registros-consultados/15871#comment28994_15871 e a solução posta na duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15893/

Comment: Você tem todo direito de negativar, no entanto, fica fácil fazê-lo tendo editado a resposta original várias vezes, ao passo que eu li a pergunta, entendi os requerimentos, ampliei o contexto e dei uma única resposta precisa. Pior! No estado atual, sua solução sequer faz qualquer coisa no contexto original da pergunta, haja vista que nem um while tem. E um programador experiente, adaptando para funcionar comprovaria como problema o fato de executar o que está dentro da sua condição logo de início, no zero, o que invalida a lógica que, como todas, deve ser perfeita para não haver problemas.

Comment: Há o histórico de edições que comprova o momento das minhas respostas, o momento da edição do autor, e tudo que foi alterado. Retórica é fútil. O resto, é programação.

Comment: Se isso te deixa satisfeito, não irei mais discutir.

Answer (score 6):

> Atualizado para demonstrar que a solução também atende à atualização da pergunta

Basta inserir isto dentro do while (mantendo o `$contador = 0` original do lado de fora):

```
if( $contador++ % 1000 == 0 ){
    echo "<br /><br />";
    // Nessa linha cria-se o próximo arquivo de captação, que pode ter 1000 emails OU MENOS.
}
// Nessa linha, grava-se cada um dos emails no arquivo criado acima
```

Assim a cada 1000 registros ele colocará uma linha em branco a mais.

Edit: Essa solução é parecida com a do @Lucas Henrique, a diferença é que usei o módulo ( % ) para contar a cada 1000, e ele usou um contador que zera. O resultado deve ser o mesmo.

Notar que esta linha do código original não faz o sentido, seria o caso de um fetch. Vide resposta do Lucas:

```
while($contador = mysql_num_rows($consulta)){
```

Comment: Ficou uma lacuna ai. O último loop não tem 1000 registros, tem por exemplo 640 registros, como insira o '<br><br>' no fundo do último loop. Obrigado.

Comment: O problema é que você perguntou uma coisa querendo outra, e sua edição mudou o sentido da pergunta. Conforme sugeri, edite a pergunta coloque o código que usa pra gerar os arquivos, aí vemos se precisa alterar algo. O que dá pra fazer é mudar ++$contador para $contador++, aí você teria o <br> pro primeiro grupo também (como se fosse o "Abrir novo arquivo"). Aí mostraria 14 vezes o <br>. Ou, colocar um echo a mais fora do loop. Depende de como você gera o arquivo, pra saber onde mexer.

Answer (score 4):

Coloquei um contador e a alterei para o [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

```
<?php

// Conectando com o banco de dados
require_once("../conecta.php");

// Chama classe para capturar os registros
require_once("excelwriter.class.php");

// Conta a quantidade de registros
$result = mysql_query("SELECT nomeUser, emailUser FROM si_login WHERE nomeUser != '' AND emailUser != ''");
$contador = 0;

// Instrução até chegar na quantidade final de registros
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $contador++;
    // aqui irá o script a cada 1000 registros.
    if($contador == 1000){
        echo "<br /><br />";
        $contador = 0;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Ficou uma lacuna ai. O último loop não tem 1000 registros, tem por exemplo 640 registros, como insira o '<br><br>' no fundo do último loop. Obrigado.

Comment: @marcosvinicius Coloque `echo "<br /><br />";` fora do while, assim, ao fim que todos os registros vai imprimir.