# Criação de arquivos para registro de dados do banco

Tags: php

Tenho 13640 usuários e estou criando 1 arquivo de captação de e-mails para cada 1000 usuários. Com o código que eu tenho, ele gera 13 arquivos e tem um sobra de 640 usuários que ficam pra traz pois não atingiu contador 1000. Assim ficam 13 arquivos em vez de 14, o último que não é criado guardaria não 1000, mais o restante (640).

O código que estou usando para criar os arquivos dentro da pasta é este:

```
// Instrução até chegar na quantidade final de registros
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    $contador++;

    if($contador == 1000){

        $excel      = new ExcelWriter("listas/report".rand(10000, 99999).".xls");

        $contador = 0;

    }

}
```

A variável $excel se encarrega através de uma classe de criar estes arquivos cada vez que acontece o loop mas não cria o último arquivo pois não atinge 1000 registros e sim 640. Como poderia editar este código para chegar ao resultado desejado?

Answer (score 4):

```
$contador = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
   if( $contador++ % 1000 == 0 ) { // assim teremos um ExcelWriter no 1o item de cada 1000.
      $excel = new ExcelWriter("listas/report".rand(10000, 99999).".xls");
   }
   echo $row['email']; // troque pro campo correto da base de dados, apenas para teste
   $excel... // ponha aqui o método que escreve a linha no Excelwriter criado
             // pois essa parte do loop é executada para cada um dos itens, incluindo
             // os 640 finais.
}
```

Isso é só um esboço, desconheço detalhes do ExcelWriter, mas acredito que resolva.