# Como inserir um cabeçalho a cada N registros?

Tags: php, loop

Como posso inserir um cabeçalho a cada N registros? Tipo ...

```
<h1>CABECALHO</h1>
     Cadastro 1
     Cadastro 2
     Cadastro 3
     Cadastro N
<h1>CABECALHO</h1>
     Cadastro ..
     Cadastro ..
     Cadastro ..
     Cadastro N
<h1>CABECALHO</h1>
     Cadastro ..
     Cadastro ..
     Cadastro ..
     Cadastro N
<h1>CABECALHO</h1>
     Cadastro ..
     Cadastro ..
     Cadastro ..
     Cadastro N
```

Mysql faz isso na listagem dos registros.

Comment: faça um `$i=0` loop `$i++` e quando `$i===4` você imprime o cabeçalho.

Comment: O que esta é diferente desta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15869/executar-script-a-cada-1000-registros-consultados

Comment: @bigown Em ambas a resposta é o operador de módulo, mas esta vai direto ao ponto. Acho que dá para conviver com as duas, mas se fosse pra fechar eu fecharia a outra como duplicata desta.

Answer (score 11):

Você precisa do [operador de Módulo (`%`)](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.arithmetic.php), que é o resto da divisão de `$a` por `$b`. Antes do loop abrimos um contador com `0` e vamos incrementando `$count++`.
E quando `( $count % 4 ) === 0` imprimimos o cabeçalho.

```
$count = 0;
foreach( $array_var as $item ){
    if( ( $count % 4) === 0 )
        echo '<h1>CABECALHO</h1>'; // aspas simples quando não tem PHP dentro
    echo "$item<br />";           // duplas quando queremos imprimir variáveis dentro da string
    $count++;
}
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/uVOPFZ)

Answer (score 3):

Outra maneira de se fazer isso sem utilizar um array de contagem é através do [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-chunk.php).

Ele irá segmentar seu array a cada N elementos gerando um segundo array. Basta inserir o cabeçalho entre eles:

```
<?php

    $cadastros = ['item1', '...', 'itemN'];
    
    $numeroSegmentos = 5;

    foreach (array_chunk($cadastros, $numeroSegmentos) as $chunks) {
        echo "Cabeçalho\n";
        
        foreach ($chunks as $cadastro) {
            echo "\t$cadastro\n";
        }
    }
```